# windouws10の削除したファイルを復元するコマンド教えてください

Tags: windows

windouws10で間違えて削除したフィルターをコマンドを使って復元してみたいです．ゴミ箱で削除してしまいました実験用に新しくファイルを作って削除してコマンドてちゃんと復元的るか試してみたいです検索したら復元無料ソフトがいろいろありましたか復元効果は何が誓うのでしょうか？コマンドが検索しても良くわかりませんでした復元のやり方詳しく教えてください

Comment: 貴方が調べたというソフトや自分で理解していると思うその内容・特徴の情報をあらかじめ質問に記述しておいてください。そうすれば答える人がそれについて重複して調べたり回答する無駄を省けます。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 「Windows10 削除ファイル 復元」をキーワードに検索するとこんな記事が見つかります。[誤ってデータを削除してしまったときの復元手順 \[Windows 11/Windows 10\]](https://www.buffalo.jp/topics/trouble/detail/recovery_0028.html), [Win10で完全に削除したファイルの復元方法](https://jp.easeus.com/file-recovery/recover-permanently-deleted-files-in-windows-10.html), [Windows 10で誤って削除したファイルを復元する5つの方法](https://www.lifehacker.jp/article/232241ways-restore-deleted-files-windows-10/), [パソコンから完全に削除したファイルを復元する](https://4ddig.tenorshare.com/jp/computer-data-recovery/recover-deleted-file-on-windows.html) 他にもいっぱいあってだいたい自社のソフトやサービスとからめた宣伝記事ですが、手順であってコマンド１つだけと言うのは無さそうですね。

Answer (score 1):

Windows のファイル削除（と復元）にはいろいろなレベルがありますが、どれを期待しているかで話は違ってきそうです。

- ゴミ箱に入れただけから復元
- ゴミ箱を空にした後復元
- ファイルの履歴機能で復元
- 以前のバージョンで復元
- `DeleteFile()` でファイルだけ削除した場合の復元
- さらに `RemoveDirectory()` もした場合の復元
- Trim / defrag してしまった場合の復元
- 非 Windows Server な (端的には smb/cifs サーバ）ネットワークファイルの復元

下に行けば行くほど困難になります（ってか Trim してしまうと事実上不可能）

ファイル復元ソフトってのがいっぱいあるのも、上記のどれに対応しているかの違いだったり、 GUI の有無だったり、想定ユーザー層の違いだったりします。ツールが最終的に行うことは同じかもしれませんが。

とりあえず Windows のローカル記憶装置内ファイルの復元目的で Microsoft 公式なら `Windows File Recovery` って CUI ツールがあります。ストアアプリから検索してみてください。コマンド一発ってことだとこれかも。

具体的な操作方法講座は SO 向きではないかもしれません。特にどのソフトを使うのか決まっていない段階では書きようがありません。

なお本当にファイルを削除してしまって困っているなら、削除したファイルが使っていた記憶装置の領域を再利用されてしまうと復元不可能になってしまいます。その PC はできるだけ操作せずにツール等のダウンロードは別の PC で行うなどの工夫はいろいろ必要そうです。

Answer (score 0):

Windowsの標準のコマンドで復元するものは用意されてません
復元ソフトは全てやってることは一緒なので、効果も同じです